# Can I use DKIM verification without DKIM signing?

Tags: linux, dkim, email-server

I'm using iRedMail and im wondering if I can use only DKIM verification and dont signing emails with DKIM??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable DKIM signing in amavisd config file, then restart amavisd service:

$enable_dkim_signing = 0;

Amavisd config file could be one of below:

- RHEL/CentOS/OpenSuSE: /etc/amavisd.conf
- Debian/Ubuntu: /etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user
- FreeBSD: /usr/local/etc/amavisd.conf

Also, iRedMail has its own support forum: http://www.iredmail.org/forum/
You can always get quick response in the forum.

Comment: yes I know but if I disable signing verification still be workining??

Comment: DKIM is a just a plus, mail server can works well without it. It's recommended to read about what DKIM is: http://www.dkim.org/