# DKIM verification without signing

Tags: dkim

All guides about DKIM focuses on signing. But how to configure sendmail to verify DKIM signatures of other mail servers?

I've found this quiestion but wihtout appropriate answer
[Can I use DKIM verification without DKIM signing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/243596/can-i-use-dkim-verification-without-dkim-signing)

I have separate MTA for sendig and receiving emails and I don't use amavis.

I know how to setup DKIM signing on the sending MTA. But how to configure recieving MTA to verify DKIM signatures?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which software you're using but if it's opendkim (successor to dkim-milter), the configuration parameter you want is `Mode`.  Set this to `v` if you only want to verify.  The default is `sv`.

If you're using amavis, check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/243596/can-i-use-dkim-verification-without-dkim-signing?noredirect=1&lq=1).